# Geopandas to_sql shows geometry column as text in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, geopandas, pandas-to-sql

I am attempting to take multipolygon data from a geojson, read it into a dataframe, and then create a table in mysql containing the data.

What's weird to me is that checking the `dtype` at the end of the script will show the geometry column correctly as `geometry`. However, checking the mysql db this column is showing as `text`. Trying to convert the column to geometry or multipolygon type raises the error

> 1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

I tried the following query, which may be where my issue is?

```
ALTER TABLE [table]
MODIFY COLUMN [column] GEOMETRY
```

Similar questions gave an answer to convert the data to WKT or WKB.
However, using the to_wkb (or to_wkt) method and then running a query will result in the previously mentioned error as well. I also tried just making my own function with no luck.
Python code below.

```
import geopandas
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types


df = geopandas.read_file('geodata.geojson')

# geodataframe = df.to_wkb()

hostname="localhost"
dbname="mydbname"
uname="iamroot"
pwd = "madeyoulook"

engine = create_engine(f'''mysql://{uname}:{pwd}@{hostname}/{dbname}''')

df.to_sql('geodatacounty', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={'shape_leng': types.FLOAT , 'shape_area': types.FLOAT, '`geometry`': Geometry(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, neither `sqlalchemy` nor `geoalchemy2` have a geometry type that is directly compatible with MySQL, so the example you have that probably works for PostGIS does not generate a syntactically correct statement for MySQL. Therefore, you need to work around this, e.g. [by first importing the column as `TEXT` and later converting the data to `GEOMETRY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63332908/14015737).

If you have your polygon data in a `TEXT` type column, you can convert it a geometry using `ST_GeomFromText()`. To make sure that you can correctly store the result, create an additional column of type `GEOMETRY` (or `MULTIPOLYGON` or whatever you want) first:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tab ADD COLUMN newcolumn GEOMETRY;
```

Then update that column:

```sql
UPDATE tab SET newcolumn = ST_GeomFromText(oldcolumn);
```

---

Note:

- If you should have difficulties importing your data in the first place, [changing the encoding of your db may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34306570/14015737):

  ```sql
  ALTER DATABASE mydbname CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
  ```
- In case you encounter errors that the WKT text representations of your geometries are too large for a `TEXT` column in the first place , you can explicitly use the `dtype` parameter  of `.to_sql()` to store them in a `LONGTEXT` column:

  ```python
  from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGTEXT

  gdf.to_sql('tab', con, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype = {'geometry': LONGTEXT})
  ```

  (this also works with `MEDIUMTEXT`).

---

Full Python example that works for me in a quick test with MySQL 5.7:

```python
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, sql

hostname = 'localhost'
dbname = 'mydbname'
uname = 'iamroot'
pwd = 'madeyoulook'

engine = create_engine(f'''mysql+pymysql://{uname}:{pwd}@{hostname}/{dbname}''')

gdf = gpd.read_file('geodata.geojson')
gdf = gdf.to_wkt()

with engine.connect() as con:
    # may not be necessary, see above. 
    con.execute(sql.text("""ALTER DATABASE mydbname CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;"""))

    gdf.to_sql('tab', con, if_exists='replace', index=False)

    con.execute(sql.text("""ALTER TABLE mydbname.tab ADD COLUMN new_geometry GEOMETRY;"""))
    con.execute(sql.text("""UPDATE mydbname.tab SET new_geometry = ST_GeomFromText(geometry);"""))
```

You then should have the according column `new_geometry` of type `GEOMETRY` in the table `tab` that stores the geometry in MySQL's internal format. You can e.g. use [the MySQL Geometry Format Conversion Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html) on that column to get back the WKT representation:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsWKT(new_geometry) from tab;
```

Comment: The ```UPDATE``` query doesn't work for me. 

Using the ```.to_wkt()``` method on my dataframe returns ```Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xE9\xF0\x10\xC6O\xFD...' for column 'geometry' at row 1``` when I run this query. I get this same error if I don't try to convert the geometry column to wkt or wkb.

Using the ```to_wkb``` method returns ```Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geomfromtext.```

Comment: I have edited the post. The problem in my old answer was that the result of `ST_GeomFromText()` could not be stored in the `TEXT` column. By storing it in a new column that already is of type `GEOMETRY` you can avoid that problem. There also is a possible encoding issue involved. My answer now includes a full example that works for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the additional explanation and link to related question!